# SQL Server: LDAP query of Active Directory Group members works inconsistently

Tags: sql-server, active-directory, ldap

I am querying Active Directory from SQL Server via a Linked Server called `LDAP`.

The linked server was created thus, authenticating through a specially created service account `myDomain\ServiceAccountWithNoPermissions`.

```sql
exec master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'LDAP', @srvproduct=N'Active Directory Service Interfaces', @provider=N'ADSDSOObject', @datasrc=N'adsdatasource'
exec master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'LDAP',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=N'myDomain\ServiceAccountWithNoPermissions',@rmtpassword='########'
```

And I'm querying the members of a specific Active Directory Group with the following:

```
select *
from OpenQuery (LDAP, '
                select objectGUID, sAMAccountName
                from ''LDAP://myServer.myDomain.com/DC=myDomain,DC=com'' 
                where MemberOf=''CN=Some Group,OU=Folder,DC=myDomain,DC=com''
                order by sAMAccountName asc 
');
```

Here's my problem. The above system is working correctly for *some* Active Directory Groups and not others.

By default I think `Authenticated Users` is supposed to be able to query any User or Group objects in Active Directory. And as a test I verified that the effective permissions of `myDomain\ServiceAccountWithNoPermissions` includes "Read all properties" on Groups for which the members are both queryable and non-queryable.

What could be the difference between Groups that are queryable and non-queryable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't describe what you mean by it working incorrectly, so I can only guess. But the most obvious thing I can see is that you're querying the membership of a group by using `memberOf`. Depending on how your environment is setup, that may not give you all the results you hope for. I [wrote about this](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/06/07/what-makes-a-member.html#beware-of-memberof), but here's the important part:

Groups only get added to `memberOf` if they have a Group Scope of:

1. **Universal** and are in the same AD forest as the user, or
2. **Global** and are on the same domain.

Groups do not get added to `memberOf` if they have a Group Scope of Global and are on another domain (even if in the same forest).

On top of that, `memberOf` will only include Domain Local groups from the same domain of the server you are retrieving results from. (if you are working in a multi-domain environment and reading from a Global Catalog, this may not be the same domain the user is from)

It will also not report the user’s primary group (usually `Domain Users`), if that’s important to you, nor will it include groups on external trusted domains.

The most reliable way to find all the members of a group is to read the `member` attribute of the group itself. But if the group is used as the primary group for any users, then you would also have to [use a different way](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/06/07/what-makes-a-member.html#the-primary-group) to find those.